# Database changes between two databases

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

I have two Microsoft Access 2007 databases. They both have tables that are very similar, there are a couple of columns that are different, but most of the structure is the same.

I exported one of the tables (table A) to Excel and filtered, getting a list of rows and their keys.

What I want to do is to update rows on the other table (table B) where the keys are the same, I can't filter using the same logic because table B does not have the columns needed to filter in the same way.

What will happen is some cell in table B will be set to the value in table A, if the key for the row matches a key on the filtered table A.

My idea was to import both tables into a C# application and make the changes programmatically, but if there is an easier way, possibly a SQL based way (Or using something in Excel) to update one of the tables based on a table in a different database, I would like to use it to be able to finish faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write cross database SQL query's in ms-access. This is based on file location. Explained [here](http://web.synametrics.com/crossjoiningaccess.htm)

So you could do the same with an update query.

```
UPDATE
    s2006
SET
    s2006.col1 = s2007.col1,
    s2006.col2 = s2007.col2
FROM
    c:\data\Sales2006.Sales s2006
INNER JOIN
    c:\data\Sales2007.Sales s2007
ON
    s2006.id = s2007.id
```

This sound to me like a situation to avoid however.

Comment: Yes, I decided to make a temp table to add to the new Access database so that I could write an update against it without having to reference another database by file location. However the structure of the update query is exactly what I had needed.

Comment: I tried running the query shown and it threw a "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" and highlights the row between the last set and the FROM statement.

Comment: Nevermind, found that the set should be after the join, and that you don't need "FROM" when you are updating the table.